# Error Loading Text File in Matplotlib

Tags: python, unix, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot data from a text file (data format: "lat lon value") using matplotlib and I keep getting an error that I can't figure out how to get around.

**Data Example:**

```
42.88355    -76.78116   81
37.1417     -79.0164    81
36.65408    -83.21783   73
41.00928    -74.73628   69
42.29133    -73.71033   72
43.77714    -71.75598   83
44.41944    -72.01944   85
41.98525    -73.96409   82
```

**temp.py Script Code:**

```
from matplotlib.mlab import load
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = load("/home/weather/data/.../site_data")
# need to know nlons and nlats beforehand!
nlons = 8; nlats = 25
X = data[0::nlats,0]
Y = data[0:nlats,1]
# data is in nlons,nlats order in file, need to transpose
Z = data[:,2].reshape(nlons,nlats).transpose()
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
CS = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,20)
plt.show()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "temp.py", line 1, in <module>
from matplotlib.mlab import load
ImportError: cannot import name load
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like matplotlib.mlab.load() has been [deprecated](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html). Try using np.loadtxt instead.